# Límites para conseguir medallas en los tags

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, medallas

Voy a aprovechar la ocasión para felicitar a Diego por haber conseguido [la primera medalla de plata en un tag](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver) en este sitio, en este caso la de [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n). ¡Enhorabuena!

Y sobre la pregunta, y tras haber visto que han hecho falta varios años para conseguir una medalla de plata en un tag (no digamos una de oro), ¿es posible ajustar para cada sitio los límites necesarios para conseguir dichas medallas? Está visto que el sitio de español nunca va a tener el nivel de público (incluso aunque salgamos de beta) que tiene Stack Overflow, que es quien va dictando estos límites. Y las medallas están como incentivos para que la gente participe. Sin embargo, si el objetivo a cumplir para conseguir la medalla es casi imposible en un determinado sitio, ¿no pierden estas su sentido? ¿No se debería poder reasignar esos valores límite para que la gente se anime un poco más?

Comment: Sobre si es posible ajustar los límites necesarios para conseguir dichas medallas: no, no lo es. He buscado en [meta.se] y no he encontrado ninguna discusión al respecto, si bien no me extrañaría que se haya planteado en algún momento.

Comment: Hoy de rebote encontré una discusión en Meta.SE al respecto: [Why not scale Tag badges for beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296633/209901).

Answer (score 2):

De momento, lo que planteas es una causa perdida. No solo no se pueden alterar los requisitos de las "chapas" en los sitios Beta, sino que todas las veces que se ha pedido que lo implementen, ya sea para sitios Beta:

- [Why not scale Tag badges for beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296633/why-not-scale-tag-badges-for-beta-sites)
- [Badge requirements on beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172960/badge-requirements-on-beta-sites)
- [Reduce or remove the 200 questions restriction on Generalist Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/reduce-or-remove-the-200-questions-restriction-on-generalist-badge)

O para todos en general:

- [The generalist badge should be gold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50925/the-generalist-badge-should-be-gold)
- [Request: reduce Tag Badge requirements for a rare tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84842/request-reduce-tag-badge-requirements-for-a-rare-tag)
- [Reduce the required number of non-wiki answers for bronze/silver/gold tag badges to 10/40/100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123303/reduce-the-required-number-of-non-wiki-answers-for-bronze-silver-gold-tag-badges)

La respuesta ha sido, más o menos:

> *No, no vamos a quitarle mérito a los que ya han conseguido la misma chapa en otros sitios, en los que también fue difícil lograrla en su momento, sólo porque tu stack todavía no ha crecido lo suficiente.*

Yo doy por hecho que, por ejemplo, la Generalist o la Legendary no las va a conseguir nadie en Spanish.SE, en esta década al menos.

Comment: También pensábamos que nadie ganaría una chapa de plata y ya hay tres... Todo es cuestión de [mucho] tiempo jeje